# Can you extend a parent template in the child using Vue.js and Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

For example, I would like to have in the parent:

```
<template>
    <v-layout column justify-center align-center>
        <v-form id="myForm">
            <v-text-field v-model="formData.firstName" label="first name" />
            <v-text-field v-model="formData.lastName" label="last name" />

<!-- SOME TAG/MARKER HERE -->

        </v-form>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {},
        data() {
            return {
                formData: {
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: ''
                },
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in the child:

```
<template>
    <v-text-field v-model="formData.age" label="age" />
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        extends: Parent,
        components: {},
        data() {
            return {
                formData: {
                    age: 0
                },
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So when the child is loaded, the page shows a form with first name, last name and age.

Is it possible to do this ? How ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need the provide the Parent component and inject into the child. See vue API https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject

Comment: Do you think the concepts of slots might be helpful for you in this case? You can go through this for once: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html.